# Running TestCafe and iframe content is blocked by 'X-Frame-Options' set to 'sameorigin' directive

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

**Tool versions:**

"testcafe": "^0.23.3" - 
Chrome 74 (tested with FF also) - 
Mac OSX Mojave 10.14 (tested on Wins 10 also)

**Summary:**
An iframe on our website is coming from a 3rd party supplier, processing card payments. The iframe directive of X-Frame-Options is set to ‘sameorigin’ and this is working fine when tested manually in a normal browser instance.

But when running TestCafe the iframe is 'refused to connect', as TestCafe is serving the test site via a proxy server. The iframe directive is blocking the response content from being displayed, due to its ‘sameorigin’ security level.

I've asked the 3rd party if they can use 'allow-from' on the iframe directive, but that's not possible. So I need to figure out how to get TestCafe to view the iframe contents as this is a major blocker for us.

**Run command:**
$ npm run testChromeUi
"testChromeUi": "testcafe chrome tests/ --screenshots ./screenshots --screenshots-on-fails -e --allow-insecure-localhost --allow-running-insecure-content --dev --debug-on-fail",

**Error:**
Refused to display 'http://192.168.15.42:59242/g9fBtWYro!if/https://www.URL/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1033474/56834840-788f7380-686a-11e9-82f1-970653e9aa05.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1033474/56834842-788f7380-686a-11e9-92fb-f2d1f5048922.png

Thanks.

Comment: I think this can help you: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/working-with-iframes.html

Comment: I'm aware of that documentation. I have no problem switching to iFrames, the problem is that the iFrame directive set to 'same-origin' as a security level is being blocked from displaying when running a TestCafe browser. This is because TestCafe works by serving the test site via a proxy server, and clashes with the iFrame directive set to 'same-origin' . I need a workaround.

Comment: Let's discuss this issue here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2012.

Comment: @V.Airich Ok will do.